# Generated Rig is small and distant from Armatures

Tags: rigging

I know i can scale it and reposition it. What i want to know is what is causing this problem, why i am not getting exact scale and position of my rig as of armature. Here is SC
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply scale (and potentially other transforms) in Object Mode to the metarig first.

Comment: There are 3 options  Location, Origin parent in metarig transform properties in tool options  on top right side. Where to check Scale options

Comment: top left, object menu

Comment: It Helped, Thank you!